# "stylelint" found some error. Please fix them and try committing again

Tags: reactjs, git, react-redux, stylelint, git-husky

I am getting the error as

`Running tasks for **/*.{js,jsx} [failed] Error: No files matching the pattern "<file path>" are found.  husky > pre-commit hook failed.`

when I am trying to commit the code.
Please let me know the cause for this error or the solution if known.

Comment: The cause of the error is that you installed an error-checker, told it to check for this error, and it found this error. What part of this process has confused you? What was not helpful in the other questions you found when searching StackOverflow for "no files matching the pattern were found"? ([example search](https://www.google.com/search?q=no+files+matching+the+pattern))